# Specifiying the poster/background image of a video in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dears,

I have videos on a website in html, and the beginning of the videos is black. So the videos are appearing in black before playing. I am trying to set the poster/background/display picture or "whatever to call it" of the video from a specific minute from inside the video without using any pictre/screenshot.

Please assist if possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: Check out: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp

Comment: This only lets me add an image, but I am trying to display an image from the video. For example, if the video length is 3 mins, and instead of letting it display the beginning of the video before playing, I want to display the image from (2 mins) and hwne you start the video it will play from beginning.

Comment: Unless you want to automate the process, use a video editor and get the image you want from the video... or just full screen the video and print screen.